# In XNA, what symbols are available for conditionally-compiling platform-specific code?

Tags: xna, windows, xbox360

In XNA, what defines are set to allow me to determine if my code is running on a PC with Windows, Xbox, or Windows Phone?

Right now I am assuming it is these three:

- `WINDOWS_PHONE`
- `WINDOWS`
- `XBOX360`

Are these correct? Are there any additional symbols?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd282469.aspx), the available symbols are:

- `WINDOWS` for Windows.
- `XBOX` or `XBOX360` for the 360 and
- `WINDOWS_PHONE` for the phone.